# Prevent URL leak to free members in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a specific URL ( to E-learning html5 course in my host ) that I want to restrict access to it only to premium members in my WordPress site.
Using Paid Membership Pro plugin I can only hide the link to that URL to free members and show it to premium members…

But if my premium members give the hidden URL to free members they can access to it too…

I don't know where to start and how to find a solution to this...

**I just want to be sure that only premium members can access to that URL and if they ( Premium Members ) leak that URL to free members they never can access it...**

Sorry for my poor English :)

Any guidance or idea is extremely appreciated…

Comment: I hope you aren't paying for the `Paid Membership Pro` plugin because that sounds like poor security it offers.

Comment: What plugin or solution do you recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know wordpress. The PHP tag brought me here. Security by obscurity is no security at all. I would find another plug in that actually requires authentication.. WP has a login functionality already though. Perhaps you could use that and check the `SESSION` array to verify they meet your criteria.

Comment: "Security by obscurity is no security at all"... I totally agree with this...

Comment: If the plugin hides the page content by role, what does it matter if non-subscribers have the URL?  It looks like the plugin you mentioned supports this. You should read the documentation to learn how to use the plugin correctly.  Please note that questions asking us to suggest other plugins for your needs are off-topic per SO community guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom page template where the premium content lives. In the page template you can add some php to authenticate the user requesting the page.

```
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'premium-subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ||
        current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        // page template code goes here
    }else{
         //redirect to login page or prompt login
    }
```

Comment: Plus 1 for your answer but I don't know where to put this code :)

Comment: Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

You would create a new page template file in your theme (or child theme) named something like page-premium.php. You would want to follow the wordpress documentation for declaring the template's name. You can paste in the code from the theme's default page code if the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to follow the instructions in the plugin documentation correctly. I suggest looking at the following links:

https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/content-controls/for-posts/

https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/content-controls/for-pages/

https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/content-controls/with-shortcodes/

For each of them there is a validation type for members only

EDIT:
If the url you need to block takes directly to a file, you may have to do a configuration on the server. It can be done directly in your .htaccess file.

Here is an example of how to block a file or a specific directory. But keep in mind that direct access to this url will be impractical. In other words, this file can be injected into your site, but never downloaded directly through the url via browser.

```
<Files ~ "\.ini$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I read all of that you provided ... but the problem is that the plugin just hides the URL and content ... if you have that URL even if you're not logged in you can access that URL....

Comment: Paid Membership Pro only hides or shows the links or contents... If you have that hidden url you can access it...